# Is "Where you been" the same as "Where have you been"?

Tags: grammar

I always hear "Where you been" in movies so, is it grammatically correct or not?

Comment: Yes, it's an informal way of saying "Where have you been?"

Comment: *Very* informal... not acceptable in most instances, unless quoting a character, perhaps. "Where've you been," is more likely, in most conversations.

Comment: what do you mean by quoting a character? @DrMoishePippik

Comment: @muhammedabdelfattah about quoting a character: if you were writing a book, the words that your characters say would appear in quotes, for example **"Where you been?" said Jack.**

Comment: This is not just "informal", it's a phenomenon called **copula deletion** or the **zero copula**, and in some dialects it is standard: https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-copula-grammar-1692518

Answer (score 1):

It is very informal.  The normal expression is "Where've you been?" (and when this is spoken quickly you might not hear the "ve")

As a learner, you should use "Where've you been?".